# Powershell Automate Site Logon

Tags: powershell

I am looking to automate the logon to a phpBB site.

So I have been able to automate the navigation, username, password, and even a check box. However, I need to be able to "click" the logon button.

Here is the site code pertaining to the "Login" button:

```
   <form action="http://www.somethingorother.com/login.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateOwnerLogin()" >
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">

   <tr>
    <td width="30%" align="right" valign="top">
     Login
    </td>
    <td width="70%" align="left" valign="top">
     <input type="text" size="45" name="login" maxlength="50">
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td width="30%" align="right" valign="top">
     Password (min 4 characters)
    </td>
    <td width="70%" align="left" valign="top">
     <input type="password" size="45" name="password" maxlength="50">
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td width="30%" align="right" valign="top">
     <input type="checkbox" name="terms_read" value="yes">
    </td>
    <td width="70%" align="left" valign="top">
     By using this Login window, I agree to the Terms and Conditions.
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td width="30%" align="right" valign="top">

    </td>
    <td width="70%" align="left" valign="top">
     <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </td>
   </tr>
```

From digging around I have figure out that the "login" value might be the issue here because there are more than one. I have tried the .click() and .submit() attempts.

Always end up with:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:12 char:1
+ $submitButton = $doc.getElementById('Login')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Can I even do this with IE and hints as how? Or is there an alternative with Invoke-WebRequest?

Comment: There isn't any element with the ID `Login`. The login submit button doesn't have any ID at all, so your `$doc.getElementById('Login')` won't find anything.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the answer. If you have found the solution to your problem, post it as an answer and accept it to close out your question, and to help future SO users with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was this block on the html:

```
 </td>
    <td width="70%" align="left" valign="top">
     <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </td>
   </tr>
```

Obviously there is no "ID" to work with. However, utilizing **.getElementsByTagName** I could specify this one.

Here is the code I used to "click" the Login button.

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "submit"}
$Link.click()
```